# Показать/скрыть изображения с одним классом по нажатию javascript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы по нажатию на изображение, все остальные изображения скрывались. По повторному нажатию показывались обратно.
Все блоки имеют один класс. Попробовала через цикл, но не отработало

```js
function selectimage(item) {
  var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].style.display = "block")
      arr[i].style.display = "none";
    else
      arr[i].style.display = "block";
  }
  item.style.display = "";
}
```

```html
<div class="image" id="mount" onclick="selectimage(this)">
  <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="image">
</div>

<div class="image" id="forest" onclick="selectimage(this)">
  <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="image">
</div>

<div class="image" id="see" onclick="selectimage(this)">
  <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="image">
</div>
```

Comment: всего лишь досадная опечатка-недосмотр `if (arr[i].style.display == "block")`

Comment: да, точно, спасибо! но все равно оно срабатывает как-то кривовато: когда в первый раз покликать на любое изображение, остальные скрываются и появляются снова, но когда на любое другое потом, скрывается только одно

Comment: Написал решение в ответе. Имхо чуть более гибкое. Хотя наверняка можно еще улучшить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас была всего лишь досадная опечатка-недосмотр `if (arr[i].style.display == "block")`.

Но вот немного получше скрипт.

- Картинки складываются в массив до функции. А то получается она каждый раз дергает DOM.
- Также есть флаг `isHidden`, в зависимости от которого меняется видимость всех картинок.
- В конце работы скрипта конечно же надо изменить значение флага на противоположное и принудительно показать картинку, на которую кликнули.

```js
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
var isHidden = false;

function selectimage(item) {  
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {    
      arr[i].style.display = isHidden ? 'block' : 'none';          
  }
  
  isHidden = !isHidden;      
  item.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 190px;
  display: block;  
}

div.image {
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;  
}
```

```html
<div class="image" id="mount" onclick="selectimage(this)">
  <img src="http://proxvost.info/photo/fun/kittens/beautiful/009.jpg" alt="image">
</div>

<div class="image" id="forest" onclick="selectimage(this)">
  <img src="http://ic.pics.livejournal.com/drakonit/14191857/218163/218163_original.jpg" alt="image">
</div>

<div class="image" id="see" onclick="selectimage(this)">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SHNnbC4WJCo/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="image">
</div>
```

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Вы забыли прописать `==` в if

```
function selectimage(item) {
  var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
  {
    if (arr[i].style.display == "block")
      arr[i].style.display = "none";
    else
      arr[i].style.display = "block";
  }
  item.style.display = "";
}
```

Comment: спасибо да! но все равно оно срабатывает как-то кривовато: когда в первый раз покликать на любое изображение, остальные скрываются и появляются снова, но когда на любое другое потом, скрывается только одно

Comment: У вас this не получает параметра  display = "", поэтому у него с if проблема